# Failed to send file to AWS S3: "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

It was working perfectly, but mysteriously, the upload stopped working. I have not changed the Cognito or IAM settings.

I can download, but I can not upload. I get the following error message:

> Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=54 "Connection reset by peer"
>
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
>   2016-12-10 19:06:44.484704 aws-s3-pods[42605:831200] []
>
> nw_endpoint_handler_add_write_request [3.1 54.231.98.131:443 failed
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] cannot accept write requests 2016-12-10
>   19:06:44.485410 aws-s3-pods[42605:831243] []
>   __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [22] Invalid argument

The error happens in `upload` method, in line `transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continue` (full code bellow).

Class to interact with Amazon

```
//
//  AmazonS3.swift
//  challenge3
//
//  Created by Bruno Macabeus Aquino on 07/12/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Bruno Macabeus Aquino. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import AWSCore
import AWSS3

let REGION_TYPE = AWSRegionType.usEast1
let IDENTITY_POOL_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

enum AmazonS3DownloadErros {
    case noSuchBucket
    case noSuchKey
    case others
}

enum AmazonS3UploadErros {
    case noSuchBucket
    case others
}

class AmazonS3 {

    static let sharedInstance = AmazonS3()

    let deviceDirectoryForUploads: URL

    init() {
        // credenciais
        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
            regionType: REGION_TYPE,
            identityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL_ID)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
            region: .usEast1,
            credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        // create temp directory to make upload
        func createLocalTmpDirectory(_ directoryName: String) -> URL? {
            do {
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(directoryName)
                try
                    FileManager.default.createDirectory(
                        at: url,
                        withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                        attributes: nil)
                return url
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Creating \(directoryName) directory failed. Error: \(error)")
                return nil
            }
        }

        self.deviceDirectoryForUploads = createLocalTmpDirectory("upload")!
    }

    func download(bucket: String, key: String, errorHandle: @escaping (_ enumError: AmazonS3DownloadErros, _ taskResult: AWSTask<AnyObject>, _ error: Error) -> Void, completion: @escaping (_ resultObjectOutput: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput, _ filePath: String) -> Void) {
        let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()!
        downloadRequest.bucket = bucket
        downloadRequest.key = key

        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()!
        transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continue({
            task in
            if let error = task.error {
                let errorCode = (error._userInfo as! [String: String])["Code"]

                if errorCode == "NoSuchKey" {
                    errorHandle(.noSuchKey, task, error)
                } else if errorCode == "NoSuchBucket" {
                    errorHandle(.noSuchBucket, task, error)
                } else {
                    errorHandle(.others, task, error)
                }
            } else {
                let results = task.result! as! AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput
                let body = results.body as! NSURL

                completion(results, body.path!)
            }

            return nil
        })
    }

    func imageToUrl(image: UIImage, fileName: String) -> URL {
        let fileURL = deviceDirectoryForUploads.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        try! UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        return fileURL
    }

    func upload(bucket: String, key: String, filePath: URL, errorHandle: @escaping (_ enumError: AmazonS3UploadErros, _ taskResult: AWSTask<AnyObject>, _ error: Error) -> Void,
                completion: @escaping (_ resultObjectOutput: AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput) -> Void) {
        let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
        uploadRequest.body = filePath
        uploadRequest.key = key
        uploadRequest.bucket = bucket
        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()!
        transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continue({
            task in
            if let error = task.error {
                let errorCode = (error._userInfo as! [String: String])["Code"]

                if errorCode == "NoSuchBucket" {
                    errorHandle(.noSuchBucket, task, error)
                } else {
                    errorHandle(.others, task, error)
                }
            } else {
                let results = task.result! as! AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput

                completion(results)
            }

            return nil
        })
    }

    func uploadImage(bucket: String, key: String, image: UIImage, errorHandle: @escaping (_ enumError: AmazonS3UploadErros, _ taskResult: AWSTask<AnyObject>, _ error: Error) -> Void,
                     completion: @escaping (_ resultObjectOutput: AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput) -> Void) {
        self.upload(
            bucket: bucket,
            key: key,
            filePath: imageToUrl(image: image, fileName: key.components(separatedBy: "/").last!),
            errorHandle: errorHandle,
            completion: completion
        )
    }
}
```

To use `upload` in controller:

```
    AmazonS3.sharedInstance.uploadImage(
        bucket: "eventbeeapp",
        key: "luffy.jpg",
        image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "luffy"),
        errorHandle: {
            _, _, _ in
            print("--- ERROR ---")
    }, completion: {
        _ in
        print("--- OK ---")
    })
```